# application failed to find Chromium-edge browser

Tags: c++, microsoft-edge, webview2

I created a sample application to open a webpage on microsoft edge, by following below URL guidance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/win32

I installed packages using NuGet packet manager as instructed. Everything worked fine on development machine.

Then I copied the exe of my sample application and the library "WebView2Loader.dll" into testing machine, which has Microsoft edge Version 83.0.478.50 (Official build) (64-bit). I got "ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" error, means "Either it failed find the edge installation or version is Not compatible with SDK version". This error is on call CreateCoreWebView2Environment(), which supposed to find browser.

I am trying to find out why it is not working when it has higher version of than minimum required version. As per documentation, minimum required version of edge is 82 I have 83.0.478.50.

Let me know what I am missing on test environment? should I set any environment variables? I tried find online if there any environment variables required, couldn't find any.

Edit:

The current version Microsoft.web.webview2 SDK is 0.9.488. The testing box has edge version 83.0.478.50. I understand that I need to update my edge version on Testing machine.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by @Nic Champagne Williamson. Please check whether you are using the correct version of the MS Edge browser as per your SDK version. If the error still persists then please try to provide more information about your SDK version that may help to narrow down this issue.

Comment: @ Deepak-MSFT Edited my original post with details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the SDK package are you using?

The way to find out the minimum version of the browser for a given SDK package is to look at the build numbers. For example:
SDK version 0.9.**538** requires Edge n.n.**538**.n+

More details can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/versioning

Answer (score 0):

CreateCoreWebView2Environment or CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions returns 'FILE_NOT_FIND'?

You need webview2 runtime. You should download [WebView2 Runtime installer (Preview)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) and then run it.

Separate webview2 runtime is not necessary if there is a fully functional Microsoft edge(Chromium). But the stable channel Microsoft edge(Chromium) is not supported by now, as the webview2 is in its preview stage.